# Jenkins pipeline start failing in on when/expression clause with custom method call with No such DSL method found among steps

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

After upgrading jenkins and it's plugins to the recent versions all my pipeline based jobs have start failing in the `when/expression` clause which were trying to call custom  method defined in the current `Jenkinsfile`

Jenkins 2.50

Pipeline: Model Definition v 1.1.1

The minimal `jenkinsfile` that can reproduce the issue is here:

```
#!/usr/bin/env groovy

pipeline {
    agent {
        label "mac"
    }
    parameters {
        booleanParam (
            name : "CONDITION",
            defaultValue: false,
            description: "")
    }

    stages {
        stage("Step 1") {
            when {
                expression {
                    return condition()
                }
            }
            steps {
                externalStep()
            }
        }
    }
}

void externalStep() {
    echo "externalStep"
}

Boolean condition()
{
    return params.CONDITION
}
```

Help greatly appreciated

Error:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No such DSL method 'condition' found among steps [ansiColor, archive, bat, build, catchError, checkout, deleteDir, dir, dockerFingerprintFrom, dockerFingerprintRun, echo, emailext, emailextrecipients, envVarsForTool, error, fileExists, getContext, git, httpRequest, input, isUnix, library, libraryResource, load, mail, milestone, node, parallel, properties, publishHTML, pwd, readFile, readTrusted, resolveScm, retry, script, sh, slackSend, sleep, sshagent, stage, stash, step, svn, timeout, timestamps, tool, unarchive, unstash, validateDeclarativePipeline, waitUntil, withContext, withCredentials, withDockerContainer, withDockerRegistry, withDockerServer, withEnv, wrap, writeFile, ws] or symbols [all, allOf, always, androidLint, ant, antFromApache, antOutcome, antTarget, any, anyOf, apiToken, architecture, archiveArtifacts, artifactManager, batchFile, bitbucket, booleanParam, branch, buildButton, buildDiscarder, caseInsensitive, caseSensitive, choice, choiceParam, clock, cloud, command, configFile, configFileProvider, cron, crumb, defaultView, demand, disableConcurrentBuilds, docker, dockerfile, downloadSettings, downstream, dumb, envVars, environment, expression, file, fileParam, filePath, fingerprint, frameOptions, freeStyle, freeStyleJob, git, github, githubPush, gradle, hyperlink, hyperlinkToModels, installSource, jdk, jdkInstaller, jgit, jgitapache, jnlp, jobName, junit, label, lastDuration, lastFailure, lastGrantedAuthorities, lastStable, lastSuccess, legacy, legacySCM, list, local, location, logRotator, loggedInUsersCanDoAnything, masterBuild, maven, maven3Mojos, mavenErrors, mavenMojos, mavenWarnings, modernSCM, myView, node, nodeProperties, nonStoredPasswordParam, none, not, overrideIndexTriggers, paneStatus, parameters, password, pattern, pipeline-model, pipelineTriggers, plainText, plugin, pollSCM, projectNamingStrategy, proxy, queueItemAuthenticator, quietPeriod, run, runParam, schedule, scmRetryCount, search, security, shell, skipDefaultCheckout, skipStagesAfterUnstable, slave, stackTrace, standard, status, string, stringParam, swapSpace, text, textParam, tmpSpace, toolLocation, unsecured, upstream, usernameColonPassword, usernamePassword, viewsTabBar, weather, zfs, zip] or globals [currentBuild, docker, env, params, pipeline, scm]
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.DSL.invokeMethod(DSL.java:149)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsScript.invokeMethod(CpsScript.java:108)
    at groovy.lang.GroovyObject$invokeMethod.call(Unknown Source)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:48)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:113)
    at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.impl.Checker$1.call(Checker.java:151)
    at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.GroovyInterceptor.onMethodCall(GroovyInterceptor.java:21)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.scriptsecurity.sandbox.groovy.SandboxInterceptor.onMethodCall(SandboxInterceptor.java:115)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.scriptsecurity.sandbox.groovy.SandboxInterceptor.onMethodCall(SandboxInterceptor.java:103)
    at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.impl.Checker$1.call(Checker.java:149)
    at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.impl.Checker.checkedCall(Checker.java:146)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.sandbox.SandboxInvoker.methodCall(SandboxInvoker.java:16)
    at Script1.run(Script1.groovy:1)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.pipeline.modeldefinition.when.impl.ExpressionConditionalScript.evaluate(jar:file:/Users/Shared/Jenkins/Home/plugins/pipeline-model-definition/WEB-INF/lib/pipeline-model-definition.jar!/org/jenkinsci/plugins/pipeline/modeldefinition/when/impl/ExpressionConditionalScript.groovy:43)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.pipeline.modeldefinition.ModelInterpreter.evaluateWhen(jar:file:/Users/Shared/Jenkins/Home/plugins/pipeline-model-definition/WEB-INF/lib/pipeline-model-definition.jar!/org/jenkinsci/plugins/pipeline/modeldefinition/ModelInterpreter.groovy:420)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.pipeline.modeldefinition.ModelInterpreter.call(jar:file:/Users/Shared/Jenkins/Home/plugins/pipeline-model-definition/WEB-INF/lib/pipeline-model-definition.jar!/org/jenkinsci/plugins/pipeline/modeldefinition/ModelInterpreter.groovy:95)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.pipeline.modeldefinition.ModelInterpreter.withEnvBlock(jar:file:/Users/Shared/Jenkins/Home/plugins/pipeline-model-definition/WEB-INF/lib/pipeline-model-definition.jar!/org/jenkinsci/plugins/pipeline/modeldefinition/ModelInterpreter.groovy:223)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.pipeline.modeldefinition.ModelInterpreter.withEnvBlock(jar:file:/Users/Shared/Jenkins/Home/plugins/pipeline-model-definition/WEB-INF/lib/pipeline-model-definition.jar!/org/jenkinsci/plugins/pipeline/modeldefinition/ModelInterpreter.groovy:222)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.pipeline.modeldefinition.ModelInterpreter.call(jar:file:/Users/Shared/Jenkins/Home/plugins/pipeline-model-definition/WEB-INF/lib/pipeline-model-definition.jar!/org/jenkinsci/plugins/pipeline/modeldefinition/ModelInterpreter.groovy:94)
    at ___cps.transform___(Native Method)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.ContinuationGroup.methodCall(ContinuationGroup.java:57)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.FunctionCallBlock$ContinuationImpl.dispatchOrArg(FunctionCallBlock.java:109)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.FunctionCallBlock$ContinuationImpl.fixName(FunctionCallBlock.java:77)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor424.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.ContinuationPtr$ContinuationImpl.receive(ContinuationPtr.java:72)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.ConstantBlock.eval(ConstantBlock.java:21)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.Next.step(Next.java:74)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.Continuable.run0(Continuable.java:154)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.SandboxContinuable.access$001(SandboxContinuable.java:18)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.SandboxContinuable$1.call(SandboxContinuable.java:33)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.SandboxContinuable$1.call(SandboxContinuable.java:30)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.scriptsecurity.sandbox.groovy.GroovySandbox.runInSandbox(GroovySandbox.java:108)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.SandboxContinuable.run0(SandboxContinuable.java:30)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThread.runNextChunk(CpsThread.java:165)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup.run(CpsThreadGroup.java:328)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup.access$100(CpsThreadGroup.java:80)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup$2.call(CpsThreadGroup.java:240)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup$2.call(CpsThreadGroup.java:228)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsVmExecutorService$2.call(CpsVmExecutorService.java:64)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at hudson.remoting.SingleLaneExecutorService$1.run(SingleLaneExecutorService.java:112)
    at jenkins.util.ContextResettingExecutorService$1.run(ContextResettingExecutorService.java:28)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Finished: FAILURE
```

Comment: If it looks like a regression, then you could [file a bug](https://jenkins.io/redirect/report-an-issue/) on the 'pipeline-model-definition-plugin' component.

Comment: Yeah, I think its a regression. I will file a bug.

Comment: Filed as https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-42829

Answer (score 4):

By a comment from Andrew Bayer in the [bug 42829](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-42829):

> FYI, closed this as WON'T FIX because Declarative doesn't officially support calling methods defined elsewhere in the Jenkinsfile. It's possible that may work in the future, but not guaranteed.

So, for now, you can't do it.

Comment: Looks like this is possible in Declarative 1.2+ fwiw (so newer versions of declarative this should be working). For very complex use cases, there's also the "Scripted" pipeline syntax in which all the same functionality is possible (and more complex things that Declarative doesn't do). However, it does take restructuring Jenkinsfiles a bit since they are different syntaxes (not to mention you'll have to do a little more that the declarative takes care of for you). However the docs are good about showing how to do something in both syntaxes. https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/syntax/#compare

Comment: Confirmed that when expressions now work great in Jenkins 2.414.2!